# how to change to drupal default administer

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to edit one website which is based on drupal 6.
The problem is that this site has own administration page, so I can not to edit views for example... also can find any setting to change to default administer...

Is there any option how to turn default administer on?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say that the site has its own admin page. In almost any drupal site, the url www.your.site/admin should land on the drupal admin interface, if you are logged on as user 1

Comment: yes, but I have on this link Villa management system... what is administrative system for adding content on the site, but by adding understand add properties...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok shows up that pamatt has a true, it wants a right user to show right administration. When I wrote some sql select I discover that user admin do not have permissions... so I used another with right permissions and the drupal administrations shows up on the top of the side as thin panel...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but if it's about views admin - there's separate Views Admin UI module, it might be turned off - you need to turn it on at /admin/build/modules.